# A java-based library for FCA

Tags: java, statistics

I have had a chance to go through `Formal Concept Analysis` and found it a powerful tool for Information Retrieval (IR) topics. Nonetheless, I found it very difficult to find a comprehensive implementation for FCA, written in Java. Here are a list of Java library that I found which either of them has one or more drawbacks:

1. [Galocia](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~galicia/features.html): Although it looks like a powerful tool, but lack of documentation makes it so difficult to figure it out.
2. [FCAlib](https://github.com/julianmendez/fcalib): Although this library has a lame documentation, even the documentation is erroneous at first step:

   ```
     FormalContext<String,String> context = new FormalContext<String,String>();
     MyExpertClass expert = new MyExpertClass(context); //at this line,
     context.addAttribute("a");                         //the MyExpertClass is not defined
     context.addAttribute("b");
     context.addAttribute("c");
     context.setExpert(expert);
     expert.addExpertActionListener(context);
   ```
3. [Colibri-Java](http://www.st.cs.uni-sb.de/~lindig/#colibri): similar situation as #1.

I do not know any other libraries useful for a Java developer (except some software such as [conexp-ng](https://github.com/fcatools/conexp-ng) which are a software rather a library.

So I call for a help to introduce me a solution for this problem.